# Apache + mod_uwsgi + Django + AWS ELB on centos6

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services

I have a problem with Django application under Apache and mod_uwsgi behind Elastic Load Balancer.

Application work fine when accessing by IP or Domain Name, but if i setting ELB in front of it, Django Application stop working, i have only static files(which server by apache) and 502 BAD GATEWAY error in browser and no errors at all on the server, when trying to access Django application.

UWSGI config:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
pidfile = /var/run/uwsgi.pid
```

Httpd Config:

```
<Location / >
    SetHandler uwsgi-handler
    uWSGISocket /tmp/uwsgi.sock
</Location>
<Location /static >
    SetHandler default-handler
</Location>
<Location /static/admin/ >
    SetHandler default-handler
</Location>
<Location /media >
    SetHandler default-handler
</Location>
<Location /downloads/ >
   SetHandler default-handler
</Location>

<Directory /home/www/sources/my_project/project/static >
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from All
</Directory>
 #The rest directories also declared
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced mod_uwsgi with mod_proxy_uwsgi - works better